# Initializing structure arrays

Tags: c, struct

I'm doing a chemistry project for my school.
It's supposed to give info about any element when its atomic number is given as input.

The code is here : http://pastebin.com/42H1SZhh
( I put it there since it's like 400 lines... )

Now, at line 47, I get this error : `chemistry.c:46:3: error: expected '}' before '{' token`
It highlights the line that contains the opening brace for the element Helium...

```
{  // This line
          "HELIUM", "He", 2, 4 , -269, -272
 }
```

It don't really know why this problem occurs, as I've made sure my syntax is right...
could anyone point out where the mistake is ?
Thank you

Comment: You're missing comma's separating each array element in that initializer. (i.e after each structure  closing `}`)

Comment: "as I've made sure my syntax is right" That sounds very self-confident. How did you make that sure?

Comment: @glglgl, well I read it a few times, and couldn't find any problems like a missing '}' or a loop without braces, I didn't know they had to be seperated by commas as long as they were in different sets of braces :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing commas between your struct initializers. You get the error message in question because without a comma, the compiler expects the thing following the first struct initializer to be the closing brace of the enclosing array initializer.